# SQL Join From Three Tables

Tags: sql, join

I Have three tables : Cutomers, Orders and Items with some data as below

---

Table:   Items

```
Id   Name  Order_Id         price
----------------------------------
1   Item1   1               10
2   Item2   1               20
3   Item3   2               30
4   Item4   2               40
5   Item5   3               50
6   Item6   3               60
7   Item7   4               70
8   Item8   5               80
9   Item9   5               90
```

Table : Orders

```
Id     Customer_Id
----------------------
1       1
2       1
3       2
4       2
5       3
-----------------------
```

Table: Customers

```
Id   Name
------------------------
1   Alex
2   John
3   Mark
-------------------------
```

I want the SQl Query output result as

```
------------------------------------------
Name    Total    Total      Total
        Order    Orders     Items
        Price
--------------------------------------------
Alex    100        2         4
John    180        2         3
Mark    170        1         2
----------------------------------------
```

I tried with the following Query>>>>>>>>>>>>

```
Select c.Name, SUM(i.price) as 'Total Order Price', COUNT(o.Id) as 
'Total   Orders' ,COUNT(i.id) as 'Total Items'
from Customers c  
left join Orders o  
on o.Customer_Id=c.Id
left join Items i
on i.Order_Id=o.Id 
group by c.Name
```

Out Put:>>>>>>>>>>>>>

---

```
Name    Total    Total      Total
        Order    Orders     Items
        Price
--------------------------------------------
Alex    100        4         4
John    180        3         3
Mark    170        2         2
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: orders should have `item_id`, item should not have `order_id`. Otherwise you are saying that an item can only appear in one order. this should simplify your query also.

Comment: I agree with @GB that item_id should be part of order_id, but in case you  still want to have this scenario I have added a simplistic query for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your query, the easiest solution is to use `count(distinct)`:

```
Select c.Name, SUM(i.price) as TotalOrderPrice,
       COUNT(DISTINCT o.Id) as TotalOrders,
       COUNT(i.id) as TotalItems
from Customers c left join
     Orders o  
     on o.Customer_Id = c.Id left join
     Items i
     on i.Order_Id = o.Id 
group by c.Name ;
```

Don't use single quotes for column aliases.  This causes confusion, because it only works in the `select` after `as`.  Either name the columns something that does not require an escape character, or use the appropriate escape character for your database (typically double quotes, square braces, or back ticks).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using below query which use just inner join rather than left join:

```
SELECT c.name, SUM(i.price), COUNT(DISTINCT order_id), COUNT(DISTINCT i.id)  
FROM items i
     JOIN orders o ON i.order_id = o.id
     JOIN customers c ON c.id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY c.name;
```

I hope it helps.